# Validate graduation date in Rails 5 model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, model-view-controller

I am trying to make sure that users have a valid graduation date within my application. Not sure if my variable for the current_year will be updated every time I want to validate a user's graduation date. Here is what I have (I am making this field optional for users):

```
current_year = Time.now.year 

if !(:grad_year.nil?)
        validates :grad_year, numericality: { greater_than_or_equal_to: current_year, less_than_or_equal_to: current_year + 5 }
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 validates :grad_year, numericality: { greater_than_or_equal_to: Date.today.year, less_than_or_equal_to: Date.today.year + 5 }, allow_nil: true
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it is not correct to use `Date.today.year` for validation because the current year will be hardcoded on Rails start and won't update next year (until you restart Rails).

Use Lambda instead:

```
validates :grad_year, numericality: { greater_than_or_equal_to: -> { Date.today.year }, less_than_or_equal_to: -> { Date.today.year + 5 } }, allow_nil: true
```